# Designing a function that takes two abstract Base class objects as arguments, and does different things based on what Derived class the objects are

Tags: c++, polymorphism, rtti

**==EDIT 3==**

In the end, I just added a `checkIntersect(Shape)` and `checkIntersectSpecific(Circle/Polygon/Triangle)` abstract methods to `Shape` and made them call my free (non-member) functions which were already implemented and in one place, while using some preprocessor and header tricks to save myself some duplicate code, in case I need to add other subclasses. For completion's sake, I'll mark Jefffrey's answer because his is the closest to what I did, however I'm thankful to all of you for showing me some cool stuff I actually didn't know about (function templates) and linking me to the other 2 questions which also proposed **Visitor/Double dispatch** as a solution.

*Although I have to say, I hope we see multimethods in C++ soon.*

**==EDIT OVER==**

So I have a base class `Shape` with its children: `Triangle`, `Polygon`, `Circle` and `Vector` and 10 static functions which take different pairs of the said children to check if they intersect.
I also have a GameObject class, which has a `Shape*` member, and I want to implement collision detection. For that reason, I need something like a `bool checkIntersection(Shape*, Shape*)` to work for any kinds of shapes.

My original idea was to just have a `(Shape, Shape)` function and somehow check the types of the Shapes, then call an appropriate intersection check function, but I read that this is called RTTI and is generally considered bad. I read about Visitors and Double dispatch, but the way I see it, these don't really solve my problem. Then again, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. Anyhow, now I'm stuck. I barely even managed to think of a title for this.

EDIT2: It doesn't necessarily need to be designed like this. I just need to to be somewhat easily maintainable, and preferrably without the need to update every Shape subclass if I decide to add another subclass later on.

EDIT:
To clarify, here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
class Shape {...} //this is an abstract class
class Circle : public Shape {...}
class Triangle : public Shape {...} 
class Polygon : public Shape {...}

bool checkIntersection(const Shape &s1, const Shape &s2)
{
//Do some magic and call the right function
}

bool checkIntersection(const Circle &c, const Triangle &t) {..check...}
bool checkIntersection(const Circle &c, const Polygon &p) {...check...}
//and the rest of the functions for the different combinations

class GameObject
{
    Shape * shape;//Shape is abstract
    bool collidesWith(const GameObject& obj)
    {
        return checkIntersection(*this->shape, *obj.shape);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"but I read that this is called RTTI and is generally considered bad"_, not generally. If a `dynamic_cast` can solve your problems in an easy way and isn't about to clutter your code, just use it.

Comment: It is possible to use a modified visitor pattern to solve this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11381774/3422652. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6163457/3422652

Comment: I took a look at that, but in all honesty, I think making an Everyone-visits-everyone kind of thing would be a nightmare. For the time being, I macro'ed this(I know, ugly) : `if(typeid(s1)==typeid(t1) && typeid(s2)==typeid(t2)) return intersect(dynamic_cast<t1> s1, dynamic_cast<t2>)` and basically made a very long if-this-do-that list in the `(Shape, Shape)` function. Meanwhile I'm considering making my own RTTI system *OR* making `Polygon` the base and rewriting everything with that in mind.

Comment: Perhaps this is just not a good problem to employ object-oriented programming. How many concrete classes will you have, anyway? When it comes down to it, circles and polygons may be all you really need.

Comment: "Although I have to say, I hope we see multimethods in C++ soon" multimethods could be implemented in C++ (even before C++11) with template metaprogramming. If you want more information on this, check out  Andrei Alexandrescu's book "Modern C++ Programming". I think the last chapter is about multimethods in C++ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to erase the type to then use the type. That makes little sense. Simply use overloading. No need to use a base class there:

```
checkIntersection(const& Triangle, const& Polygon) { ... }
checkIntersection(const& Triangle, const& Circle) { ... }
// ...

checkIntersection(const& Polygon p, const& Triangle t) {
    return checkIntersection(t, p);
}
// ...
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have, except that when I call `checkIntersection` with `Shape` pointers or references, it doesn't know what to do.

Comment: @Stealthmate That's why you shouldn't use `Shape` pointers or references, but use the types.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using templates. As you probably will have to implement the intersection logic for all possible Shape combinations, you may do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ShapeA {};

struct ShapeB {};

struct ShapeC {};
struct ShapeD {};

template <class A, class B>
bool checkIntersection(A& a, B& b)
{
    // intersection Logic (generic) 
}

// you can implement specific logic for some intersections
template <>
bool checkIntersection<ShapeA,ShapeB>(ShapeA& a, ShapeB& b)
{
    cout << "Intersection for ShapeA and ShapeB" << endl;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    ShapeA a; 
    ShapeB b;
    ShapeC c;
    ShapeD d;
    checkIntersection(a,b);
    checkIntersection(a,a);
    checkIntersection(c,b);
    // and so on. The beauty here is the function guessing the input parameter types
    return 0;
}
```

Some of the advantages that I see in this approach are:
 1) No type checking (no casts, no switch/case code, follows the Open/Close Principle).
 2) You can still combine it with inheritance.

Templates of course have drawbacks and there is no silver bullet for this case, but I found it specially nice in this case when you can let a template function worry about the parameter types :)

I hope that it helps!

Comment: there are 4 shapes , each can intersect with each other which makes about 16 types of intersections. templating it can cause the compiler to produce 16 different functions that can really bloat up the final size of the EXE

Comment: @user3613500 I think that's not right, template code is only compiled if used. In the case of using all the possible shape combinations you would end up having as much  compiled code as in the subclass case.

Comment: @user3613500 Right now I think I'm fine with that trade-off. Though I have a question: If I have: `Shape *a, *b` and call the function with those, will it automatically downcast to whatever `a` and `b` are?

Comment: if you insist to pass pointers to KeillRandor example, you will have to downcast the pointers , or user virtual functions

Comment: @user3613500 is right. BTW with the template example you can work with references instead of passing the objects (I edited that).

Answer (score -1):

Different Idea : use Shape enum

```
enum class ShapeType{
Triangle ,
Circle
}
```

now , each shape will have ShapeType as inner member variable

```
class Shape{
private:
ShapeType m_ShapeType;
}
```

each shape will initialize the variable to the right type in it's constructor.

now in Shape create a function which return ShapeType:

```
ShapeType getType (){
  return m_ShapeType;
}
```

in `Shape :: checkIntrsection (Shape* , Shape*)`
just make each Shape* return the type and you know the type.